# Backend SFMC not available in Data Views

Tags: marketing-cloud, data, azure

A previous employee was able to insert a number of SFMC tables into SSMS, but I do not see how he did it.

Tables like Account, AccountUser, Business Unit, etc. are not data views available in SFMC. See my screenshots.[image: Screenshots of tables not available as data views, but in our instance of SSMS]

Is there another way that data is being accessed? I'm not sure where else to look since they are not in the data views diagram.

Answer (score -1):

I see how the data was retrieved he used the SOAP APIs directly and not  the Marketing Cloud UI. See the docs here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/soap_web_service_objects.html

Comment: Salesforce has a bad reputation when it comes to breaking links. This answer would be a lot better if you went into more detail about what you did. As is, this link is just to a list of SOAP objects (object names, field types) and is not really useful.

Comment: As Derek says, if you could document this answer a little that would be great - it's also totally fine to accept your own answer as correct